# Full Crawl never stops (the crawl is getting stuck) in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, sharepoint-search, crawl, farm-admin

I am facing a problem that Full Crawl never stops (the crawl is getting stuck) in SharePoint 2013. I have stopped the crawl and started it again still taking more tine than usual. It usually completes in 6 Hrs but it took more than 100 hrs and still running.

In ULS logs i can see the below error. Can any one help on how to resolve this issue?

Filter daemon process ( 0000000000028EE0 ) is dead. TerminateProcess...         [fltrpool.cxx:1417]  search\native\gather\gthrsvc\fltrpool.cxx

[image]

Comment: I can't answer your question specifically, but on my SP farm the Sharepoint updates had not been installed for 18-24 months.  Once the updates were installed it helped speed up the crawls again.  We had the same problem of search crawls not completing according to the weekend schedule where the crawl was scheduled to run.  We had to manually stop the crawls as they were slowing down the entire SP system,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restart following service in services.msc:

1. Restart SharePoint Server search 15
2. Restart SharePoint Timer Service

If the issue still exists, delete the existing SSA and recreate the search service application to check if crawl works well.